# How can I take the sum of table view cells' data in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to add up all of the amount data and send to a different table view cell. I think I need to convert String to Double before I can do this, but I'm not sure how to do this either. Does anyone know how you can take the sum of data and present it somewhere else? I'm very new to swift and am having trouble figuring out where I need to write this code.

```
import Foundation

struct Income: Codable {
    var name: String
    var amount: String

    init(name: String, amount: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.amount = amount
    }


    static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

    static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("incomes").appendingPathExtension("plist")

    static func loadSampleIncomes() -> [Income] {
        return [
            Income(name: "Main Income", amount: "0"),
            Income(name: "Secondary Income", amount: "0"),
            Income(name: "Interest Income", amount: "0")]

    }

    static func saveToFile(incomes: [Income]) {
           let propertyListEncoder = PropertyListEncoder()
           let codedIncomes = try? propertyListEncoder.encode(incomes)

           try? codedIncomes?.write(to: ArchiveURL, options: .noFileProtection)

    }

    static func loadFromFile() -> [Income]? {
            guard let codedIncomes = try? Data(contentsOf: ArchiveURL) else { return nil }

            let propertyListDecoder = PropertyListDecoder()

            return try? propertyListDecoder.decode(Array<Income>.self, from: codedIncomes)
    }

}
```

```
import UIKit

class IncomeTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var incomes: [Income] = []


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)

if let savedIncomes = Income.loadFromFile() {
        incomes = savedIncomes
    } else {
        incomes = Income.loadSampleIncomes()
    }
}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    tableView.reloadData()
}

// table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
     return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       if section == 0 {
           return incomes.count
       } else {
           return 0
       }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "incomeCell", for: indexPath) as! IncomeTableViewCell

    let income = incomes[indexPath.row]

    cell.update(with: income)
    cell.showsReorderControl = true

    return cell

}



// MARK: - Table view delegate

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
    return .delete

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit
    editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath:
    IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            incomes.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: . automatic)
            Income.saveToFile(incomes: incomes)
       }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {
      let movedIncome = incomes.remove(at: fromIndexPath.row)
      incomes.insert(movedIncome, at: to.row)
      tableView.reloadData()

}

@IBAction func editButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let tableViewEditingMode = tableView.isEditing

    tableView.setEditing(!tableViewEditingMode, animated: true)
}

// Navigation

@IBAction func unwindToIncomeTableView(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    guard segue.identifier == "saveIncomeUnwind",
    let sourceViewController = segue.source as? AddEditIncomeTableViewController,

    let income = sourceViewController.income else { return }
        if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            incomes[selectedIndexPath.row] = income
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath],
            with: .none)
        } else {
            let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: incomes.count, section: 0)
            incomes.append(income)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
        }

        Income.saveToFile(incomes: incomes)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "EditIncome" {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let income = incomes[indexPath.row]
        let navController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let addEditIncomeTableViewController = navController.topViewController as! AddEditIncomeTableViewController

        addEditIncomeTableViewController.income = income
    }
}


}
```

```
import UIKit

class AddEditIncomeTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var incomeNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var incomeAmountTextField: UITextField!

    var income: Income?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let income = income {
            incomeNameTextField.text = income.name
            incomeAmountTextField.text = income.amount


        }

        updateSaveButtonState()
    }



    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:
      Any?) {
          super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

          guard segue.identifier == "saveIncomeUnwind" else { return }

          let name = incomeNameTextField.text ?? ""
          let amount = incomeAmountTextField.text ?? ""
          income = Income(name: name, amount: amount)
    }

    func updateSaveButtonState() {
            let nameText = incomeNameTextField.text ?? ""
            let amountText = incomeAmountTextField.text ?? ""
            saveButton.isEnabled = !nameText.isEmpty && !amountText.isEmpty
        }

    @IBAction func textEditingChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
    updateSaveButtonState()


    }


}
```

this is the table view controller in which I want the new data to be presented.

```
    import UIKit

    class BudgetHomeTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var incomes: [Income] = []
    var expenses: [Expense] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)

        if let savedIncomes = Income.loadFromFile() {
            incomes = savedIncomes
        } else {
            incomes = Income.loadSampleIncomes()
        }

        if let savedExpenses = Expense.loadFromFile() {
            expenses = savedExpenses
        } else {
            expenses = Expense.loadSampleExpenses()
        } 
    }
    }
```

This is the cell where the data will be presented specifically

```
    import UIKit

    class BugetBalanceCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var budgetBalanceText: UILabel!

    var incomes: [Income] = []
    var expenses: [Expense] = []




    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

     let incomeTotal = incomes.map({Double($0.amount) ?? 0}).reduce(0, +)
     let expenseTotal = expenses.map({Double($0.amount) ?? 0}).reduce(0, +)

     let balance = incomeTotal - expenseTotal


    }




    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: where do you want to show the sum of income?

Comment: @DilanAnuruddha I want to show it on a different new table view controller cell. I basically have all of this code but for expenses too. I want to take the sums of each and show a balance between the two. Income - Expenses.

Comment: In this code only have incomes.how you get the expenses?

Comment: @DilanAnuruddhaI have ExpenseTableViewController, AddEditExpensesTableViewController etc. I have the exact same code and table views for income as I do for expenses. I didn't show the expenses code. If I created a new TableViewController how would I show the balance in there?

Comment: you can use my answer in next tableview controller to show the blance

Comment: I think you want to show total in BudgetHomeTableViewController-> BugetBalanceCell
so  yon have to set total in cellForItemAt function. not awakeFromNib

Answer (score 1):

First define your income,expenses arrays and load data

```
var incomes: [Income] = []
var expenses: [Income] = []


if let savedIncomes = Income.loadFromFile() {
    incomes = savedIncomes
} else {
    incomes = Income.loadSampleIncomes()
}

//do the same thing for load data to expenses array
```

you can get your balance = incomes - expenses using

```
let incomeTotal = incomes.map({Double($0.amount) ?? 0}).reduce(0, +)
let expenseTotal = expenses.map({Double($0.amount) ?? 0}).reduce(0, +)

let balance = incomeTotal - expenseTotal
```

use this value where you want to show in next Table View conntroller

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I'm getting an error "Use of unresolved identifier 'incomes'" and "Use of unresolved identifier 'expenses'"

Comment: you need to define these two arrays in next tableviewcontroller and load data to array first

Comment: I've implemented the top portion into my new tableview controller. Do I put the bottom inside a tableview cell?

Comment: "Use of unresolved identifier 'incomes', Use of unresolved identifier 'expenses'" when I put in in the table view cell. I must be doing something wrong, but thanks for trying to help anyways!

Comment: I need to connect it to a UILabel!

Comment: I hope the updated code helps. I'm sure most of it is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
(income as NSArray).valueForKeyPath("@sum.self")
```

Comment: where do I put this

Comment: It is better to do this with the reduce function on a Swift Array. Casting a Swift array to an NSArray doesn't come toll free.